# Angularjs and Laravel service is not call?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm using Angularjs and Laravel5. when i call autocomplete textbox, service call no response. my code is....

**userdefined.js**

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http){

      $http.get("http://localhost:85/xamppserver/CODE_8JULY2015/public/front/state/w")
       .success(function(response) {
        $scope.availableTags = response;
        });  




    $scope.complete=function(){
      console.log($scope.availableTags);
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: $scope.availableTags
    });
    } 

  });
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
                    <label>State</label>                    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State" id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()">                                        
                </div>
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('state/{statename}', ['as' => 'customer','uses' => 'CustomerController@selectstate']);
```

**CustomerController.php**

```
public function selectstate($statename)
    {       
        //$customer = new Customer();               
        //$result = $customer->where('client_state','like', '%'.$Filter.'%')->get(array('client_state'));

        $state = new State();       
        $result = $state->where('state_name','like', '%'.$statename.'%')->get(array('state_name'));

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

how to call service using angularjs?

Comment: When you put that URL in your browser "http://localhost:85/xamppserver/CODE_8JULY2015/public/front/state/w" do you get a response you expect?

Comment: yes i got response on json format like [{"state_name":"West Bengal"}]

Comment: Any errors in the JS console? Is the request sent at all? Do you get response? add console.log(response) in your success handler and paste the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing else you can put $http.get in one function and then call it.

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http){
getstate();
function getstate(){
      $http.get("http://localhost:85/xamppserver/CODE_8JULY2015/public/front/state/w")
       .success(function(response) {
        $scope.availableTags = response;
        });  
}



    $scope.complete=function(){
      console.log($scope.availableTags);
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: $scope.availableTags
    });
    } 

  });
```